# Testing Conditions with validate_uniqueness_of

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, shoulda

Class Person:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates_uniqueness_of :user_name, scope: :account_id
end
```

For the Person Class, I can test it using the validate_uniqueness_of testing method, something like:

```
it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:user_name).scoped_to(:account_id)
```

Class Article:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :title, conditions: -> { where.not(status: 'archived') }
end
```

However, I can't seem to be able to find the equivalent "shoulda-matcher" testing method with `validate_uniqueness_of` for my Article class which contains `conditions` in the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/Shoulda%2FMatchers%2FActiveRecord%3Avalidate_uniqueness_of).

I have searched on google but I still can't seem to find a solution. Do I have to write a custom testing method for this?

Comment: Anyone who can answer this is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You can't, write a test for it manually.

Comment: @tpbowden, cheers done it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've [known](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/640) about this for a little while now, but unfortunately we haven't addressed it yet. As tpbowden said, you'll have to test it manually. Sorry :(

Comment: Would be great if this is added in the future! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: it's 2020, have this been fixed yet?

Comment: @Mr. Rene It hasn't, but we will gladly take a PR to fix it.